# Gitlab flow and previewing work in progress / staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm moving my project to gitlab and looking at their [flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html) and trying to get my head round CI as part of the process.

My project is in Rails and looking at lots of examples on line, people use the gitlab flow with a master branch and feature branches. They merge to master with a pull request and then deploy to staging, then either use tags to deploy to production or have a seperate production branch.

I like the idea of using tags as it suits my project.

So successfull changes in a feature branch get merged to master and deployed to staging where they are visible and then once tested its tagged and deployed to production. Happy with that.

The question (confusion) i have is.. the above is fine but assumes everthying is merged into master.

What is the strategy if you want to deploy changes somewhere which are not ready to go to master? ie you want to preview changes as they are developed

I've seen some people suggest evey developer should have a public version of thier working copy but that seems hard to manage especially with remote developers. What if two developers were working on the same feature branch?

Is it a case of having a seperate branch for this?

Or have i missed the point?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, I think what you probably want to do is to have [separate environment branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html#environment-branches-with-gitlab-flow). So you're not only working within your master branch, you have different branches that your changes move between (and can thus be deployed wherever) before they get to the production branch.

Comment: Thanks! I did look at this but they seem to be for changes after the code is merged with master. I'm really imagining  the senario that someone says what about feature X, i make a featue branch, code it up and want to desmostrate the changes. The code is not ready to go to master yet.